# Image within \maketitle - not separate page

Tags: graphics, titles

I would like to put a logo above my title, but I would also like to keep the title/author/date on the first page of text.

All of the solutions I've found so far relate to the title page package, which instigates a separate page.

Inserting a figure turns the first page into a 'regular' page, with header and footer, followed by the title on the next page.

I'm using article class.

Any suggestions?

Code below is slightly modified from XeLaTeX template to provide MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper}              

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Hoefler Text}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Gill Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Andale Mono}

\title{Brief Article}
\author{The Author}
\date{}     

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Content of document, starting straight away, same page...
I would like the image to have appeared at the top, above Brief Article.
    But where to put the command?


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `titling` package is what you're looking for:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper}              

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % the demo option is just for the example
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Hoefler Text}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Ligatures=TeX]{Gill Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Andale Mono}

\pretitle{%
  \begin{center}
  \LARGE
  \includegraphics[width=6cm,height=2cm]{logo}\\[\bigskipamount]
}
\posttitle{\end{center}}

\begin{document}

\title{Brief Article}
\author{The Author}
\date{}     

\maketitle

Content of document, starting straight away, same page...
I would like the image to have appeared at the top, above Brief Article.
    But where to put the command?


\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you're using a quite old syntax for loading fonts.

Comment: This is the one, easy as pie. Especially as I am actually using the titling package in the report. I noticed you have changed \setmainfont for \setromanfont etc.

Comment: I've found a problem with this: changing the justification from centre to raggedleft makes the title itself raggedright.

Comment: @Pwdr Maybe you want only the image flush left?

Comment: Flush right, but even still, the title moves with it in this example - because the command to \end{flushright} is in \posttitle{}. Moving it to the last line of \pretitle makes the title itself go to flushleft.

Comment: @Pwdr Don't add a `flushleft` environment, but just `\hfill` in front of `\includegraphics`, which will override the centering just for that line.

Answer (score 12):

Why don't you simply add the picture in to the title like

```
\title[Brief Article]{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}\\ Brief Article}
```

As noted by Barbara, since an article title becomes a running head, it is better to use the optional argument with suitable text for use as header.

Full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Hoefler Text}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Gill Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Andale Mono}

\title[Brief Article]{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}\\ Brief Article}
\author{The Author}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Content of document, starting straight away, same page...
I would like the image to have appeared at the top, above Brief Article.
    But where to put the command?


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: since an article title becomes a running head, it would be a good idea to use the optional argument for `\title` to provide suitable text.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Fair point :) Edited with thanks.

Comment: I could even put a complete `tikzpicture` environment in there. Ugly as hell but worked nicely!

Comment: That doesn't work. It gives you `LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}`.