# How to put an image on maketitle page below the author's name

Tags: graphics, titles

latex newb here.

I used a solution proposed here [Image within \maketitle - not separate page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159104/image-within-maketitle-not-separate-page) which recommended using the titling package but was only able to fiddle enough to get the image on the top of the title, which isn't what I want.

Here is the code taken out of that link(modified a bit):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}         

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{titling}

\pretitle{%
\begin{center}
\LARGE
\includegraphics[width=6cm,height=2cm]{logo}\\[\bigskipamount]
}
\posttitle{\end{center}}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{}     

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

What I want is this:
[image: book page layout]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to redefine the `\maketitlehook*` commands. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\bfseries\Huge}
\title{Title}
\posttitle{\\\vskip1.5cm}
\preauthor{\Large}
\author{Author}
\postauthor{}
\renewcommand\maketitlehooka{\pagestyle{empty}\centering\sffamily}
\renewcommand\maketitlehookc{\vskip2cm
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{sendak.jpg}
\vfill PUBLISHING HOUSE}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]