# How to insert figure into \maketitle?

Tags: titles

I am trying to create a cover page containing an image and the title of the report, but the image and the title appear on different pages. How can I solve this problem?

```
\documentclass[30pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[h] 
    \centering \includegraphics[width=5cm]{najah.png} 
  \end{figure} 
  \title{ATLAS Detector} 
  \author{Fatima Shahrouj\\ Departement of physics, An-Najah National University NNU, Nablus, Palestine.} 
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Share your code, please?

Comment: \documentclass[30pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{najah.png}
\end{figure}

\title{ATLAS Detector}
\author{Fatima Shahrouj\\
Departement of physics, An-Najah National University NNU, Nablus, Palestine.}
\maketitle

Comment: Please add the code to your question?

Comment: Hi, welcome. Note one thing: It is *not* mandatory to use a `figure` environment to insert images, `\includegraphics` works perfectly fine outside it as well (as demonstrated in Andreas' answer).  `figure` is a floating container, its purpose is to let LaTeX move images and their captions, in order to avoid bad page breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So [`\maketitle`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation) prints what you provided as `\title` and `\author` (amongst a few other things), but you're adding a figure before that. To add a figure to the `\maketitle`, as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159109/85834), you can use the `titling` package. It provides `\pretitle` to do stuff before the title and `\posttitle` for after. The `\pretitle` is already defined containing a `\begin{center}` so then, to get an image below the title we use `\posttitle{\includegrapics[...]{...}\end{center}}`. Your code will then become

```
\documentclass[30pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titling}

\begin{document}
  \posttitle{
  \\[\bigskipamount]\includegraphics[width=5cm]{najah.png}
  \end{center}
  }
  \title{ATLAS Detector}
  \author{Fatima Shahrouj\newline Departement of physics, An-Najah National University NNU, Nablus, Palestine.}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: yes, that works, thank you. But there is a problem with the position of the image and the writing!!

Comment: Fixed it. Just inserted it into a figure and centered it.

Comment: **Never** use a `figure` environment in a title!

Comment: Oh. I didn't know this. Sorry. Fixing it. But why though?

Comment: Taken care of! @FatimaSH: please accept the answer if it is satisfactory?

Comment: A `figure` environment is supposed to be moved around by LaTeX, which isn't wanted on a title page. You want the picture where you want it and nowhere else. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation

Comment: the title ATLAS Detector appeared above the image. How to put it under?

Comment: As I write in the answer, `\pretitle` puts it before and `\posttitle` after. So you replace `\posttitle{...}` with `\pretitle{\begin{center}\\ 
[\bigskipamount]\includegraphics[width=5cm]{najah.png} }`