# Insert image in tittle page

Tags: graphics

Im new to LaTex and this website so sorry if the question were already asked (I tried few solution that I found on the internet but nothing worked). Im simply trying to insert an image in my tittle page which is my first page, but without any sucess.

Thanks,
Léa.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\title{The use of LIDAR data to estimate seed bearing tree density in boreal forest, North Canada.
\\\large Dissertation report presented to obtain the MASTER 2 GAED degree
\\\large TELENVI Specialization (Remote Sensing/Environment)}

\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{forest-4918605_1280.jpg}
\label{fig:enter-label}
\author{Léa}
\date{March - August 2024}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\maketitle` does only print the contents setup using `\title`, `\author` and `\date`. So you have to put the image in the argument of one of these commands. But because this is a kind of misuage of these commands, I would recommend to design your title page free using a `titlepage` environment, or use an extra packages. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85904/277964 or. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159104/277964 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13912/277964 [etc.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/titles+graphics).

Comment: BTW: For a minimal working example it is recommended not to use a not available external image file. You can replace the image file, e.g., by one of the images provides by [package `mwe`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe).

Comment: Thank you for the fast anwser, Im gonna try this and let you know !

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to set the title page "by hand", using the `titlepage` environment:

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\title{The use of LIDAR data to estimate seed bearing tree density in boreal forest, North Canada.
\\\large Dissertation report presented to obtain the MASTER 2 GAED degree
\\\large TELENVI Specialization (Remote Sensing/Environment)}
\author{Léa}
\date{March - August 2024}

\begin{document}

% \maketitle
\makeatletter
\begin{titlepage}
    \vspace*{\stretch{1.0}}
    \begin{center}
        \Large\textbf{\@title}\\
        \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
        \@author\\
        \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
        \@date
        \vspace*{\stretch{1.0}}
        \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{forest-4918605_1280.jpg}
    \end{center}
    \vspace*{\stretch{2.0}}
\end{titlepage}
\makeatother

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

you can play with the arguments of the different `vspace*` to set more or less space between each line.